# Getting "java.io.IOException: Unsupported protocol version 22" while using the shared file store in Infinispan

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, infinispan

I'm getting the following exception while using file store based cache store which is shared among multiple nodes.

```
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: Unable to start cache loaders
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.start(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:174)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:168)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.persistence.spi.PersistenceException: java.io.IOException: Unsupported protocol version 22
    at org.infinispan.persistence.file.SingleFileStore.start(SingleFileStore.java:135)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.start(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:141)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unsupported protocol version 22
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverUnmarshaller.start(RiverUnmarshaller.java:1249)
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller.startObjectInput(AbstractJBossMarshaller.java:128)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.VersionAwareMarshaller.startObjectInput(VersionAwareMarshaller.java:142)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.VersionAwareMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(VersionAwareMarshaller.java:98)
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.AbstractDelegatingMarshaller.objectFromByteBuffer(AbstractDelegatingMarshaller.java:80)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.file.SingleFileStore.rebuildIndex(SingleFileStore.java:212)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.file.SingleFileStore.start(SingleFileStore.java:126)
    ... 79 more
```

This is how my cache config looks like:

```
<distributed-cache name="singletons">
        <versioning scheme="SIMPLE"/>
            <persistence passivation="false" >
                <file-store
                    path="${infinispan.dir}/broker-ds/singletons"
                    fetch-state="true" shared="true" preload="true" />
            </persistence>
        </distributed-cache>
```

Any clues on what is going wrong? I'm using Infinispan 8.1 version.

Update:

Instead of shared file based store, I've used JDBC based shared store and things worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot (yet) use the file store shared between multiple nodes. Either use a directory dedicated to each node or use a store which is capable of sharing (jdbc, jpa, cassandra).

Comment: Is it mentioned in the documentation? At least, I couldn't find it anywhere.